# How to Implement Test and Test and Set In Rust

Tags: rust, lock-free

I am trying to implement test and test and set in stable, safe Rust using standard atomics.

The ultimate goal is to create a lock-free LIFO queue using recursively defined nodes and I am trying to simply update `queue_head` to allow threads to place their `ComplexNode` into the top of the queue.

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicPtr, Ordering};
use std::ptr;

struct ComplexNode {
    next: Option<Box<ComplexNode>>,
    item: i32,
}

impl ComplexNode {
    fn new(val: i32) -> ComplexNode {
        ComplexNode {
            next: None,
            item: val,
        }
    }
}

struct ComplexQueue {
    queue_head: AtomicPtr<Box<ComplexNode>>,
}

impl ComplexQueue {
    fn new() -> ComplexQueue {
        ComplexQueue {
            queue_head: AtomicPtr::new(ptr::null_mut()),
        }
    }

    fn ttas(&self, incoming: *mut Box<ComplexNode>) {
        loop {
            let curr_head = self.queue_head.load(Ordering::Relaxed);

            unsafe {
                if curr_head.is_null() {
                    Box::from_raw(incoming).next = None;
                } else {
                    Box::from_raw(incoming).next = Some(*Box::from_raw(curr_head));
                }
            }

            if self.queue_head.compare_exchange(curr_head, incoming, Ordering::Relaxed, Ordering::Relaxed).is_ok() {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The only way I was able to get the `ttas` to *compile* is by using unsafe code. I am wondering if the same goal could be achieved without an unsafe block.

For reference, because of additional activity within my program, I am not able to pass a reference to a `ComplexNode` within `ttas`.

Comment: `Box::from_raw` is unsafe and whenever you are working with raw pointers you most likely end up having to use unsafe at some point to do anything non-trivial. The same usually holds for atomics and doing anything non-trivial (e.g., a lock-free DS and not just a counter) with it. In case you haven't seen this, it might be worth checking https://docs.rs/crossbeam-queue/0.2.1/src/crossbeam_queue/array_queue.rs.html for some ideas on how to implement your LIFO queue.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards Crossbeam. Their implementation is certainly helpful to reference. I was able to implement something closer to a `test and set` but I am ultimately left wondering if `test and test and set` is even possible given Rust's strict rules barring data races. To me, `test and test and set` seems to rely on a racy initial read followed by a synchronized `test and set` and it is that initial read which complicates things.